# how to send array from one viewcontroller to another using segue

Tags: ios, iphone, arrays, swift, uicollectionview

i have 2 view controllers and i am trying to send an array from one vc to the other and display it in a collectionview. what happens with in the app is the user takes a picture and adds it into an array which populates a collectionview in vc1 and once it is displayed in the collectionview the user can select it and send it to a uiview above the collectionview and add it to a different array, we will call it array1. i want to send array1 to array2 in the second vc. but nothing i try works.

heres some code from vc1:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {


    if segue.identifier == "segueId" {
        if let dVC = segue.destinationViewController as? ViewController2{

            dVC.array1 = array2
        }


    }
}
```

code from vc2:

```
var array2 = []{
    didSet{
        array1 = array2
    }
}
```

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in line  dVC.array1 = array2, do you hit it? can you also make sure that array2 is not empty too when you hit that line?

Comment: why don't you directly assign array2 in vc2 to the array1 of vc1?

Comment: Assign array directly.....why this unwanted overhead?

Answer (score -1):

Please,check your array2 while assigning its values into array1 if u got result in array2 then by array1 of which u have property in your second VC . Then,You can directly get result from array1.